How to install an npm package using github monorepo url
I have developed and published a private NPM package. I want to set up a development environment to test the package. I have 2 branches in GitHub: dev and prod. I and other developers want to fully test the npm package in a dev environment before publishing it publicly. So, my thinking is that we could npm install the dev module using the GitHub repo url. After it has been tested satisfactorily, we can
publish publicly the module to NPM. The GitHub repo is a Monorepo. I just need help installing it. How can I install the dev module using the GitHub repo url?
